# Azure Logic app : How to Send an Email with one or more attachments after getting the content from Blob storage?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I want to read blob contents using **azure logic app get blob contents connector** and send that contents as attachment via email using azure logic app **send email connector**.

Attachments could be one or more.

Send email requires attachment data in following json format :

```
[
  {
    "ContentBytes": "@{body('Get_blob_content')}",
    "Name": "Test"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (Preview)` as `trigger` to focus on the `Container` which you want to listen to.

Then add `Get blob content` as `action` to get the blob content.

Finally add `Send email` as action to sent email to users. Here I choose `Gmail` and as you have add `Get blob content` action, so in `Attachments Content` column you could insert `File Content` which is equal to `@{base64(body('Get_blob_content'))}`.

If you want to add one or more attachment, you only need to click `Add new item` in `Send email` action.

Here is designer screenshot and code view screenshot.
[image]
[image]

---

For attaching a dynamic number of files to an email, there is a toggle in the UI to use an input array instead

[image: toggle-for-dynamic-input]

which changes the UI to something like this

[image: dynamic-attachments-input]

The input here expects an array of items in this format

```
{
  "Name": "<NameOfFile>",
  "ContentBytes": "<Base64OfFileContent>"
}
```

Comment: Just one correction ! attachment section should be dynamically added as per count of attachment

Comment: How to achieve this for multiple containers? Just create new flow?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use array variable in below format.

```
{
  "ContentData": "<Base64OfFileContent>",
  "FileName": "FileName.txt"
}
```

Instead of "Name" I used "FileName" and instead of "ContentBytes" I used "ContentData".