# send email with attachment in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to send an email with attachment according to a condition from table. For e.g I have a table XYZ which has column "Flag" and if the column flag value is "N" then it has to pick the values with value as "N from the table and write into a file. This file has to be sent as attachment in an email in Azure data factory. f you can help with the process for this in Azure data factory it should be great.

Comment: You should do this using Azure Logic Apps wherein you can define a SQL Trigger or a SQL action basis your requirement and then chain this with an email activity to send emails along with an attachment

Comment: Can Azure logic apps able to send emails with attachment..if you can also share any useful links it would be great..

Comment: You should go through the official MSFT Azure docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my researching, there is no such activity could send email with attachment,you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/18404794-add-a-new-email-activity-with-the-ability-to-send) to improve this feature.

As workaround, you could adopt @Raunak Jhawar's suggestion that using [SQL Connector Trigger](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/).

[image]

Then you could get the value you want into [Azure File Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/) or [Azure Blob Storage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage)

After that,send email with attachments following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow). Here is s similar case for your reference:[Azure Logic app : How to Send an Email with one or more attachments after getting the content from Blob storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473878/azure-logic-app-how-to-send-an-email-with-one-or-more-attachments-after-gettin)