# How to get multiple files using GetBobContent and add as attachment to Email in Azure Logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Hi I am working in Azure Logic app. I am trying to get multiple files from azure data Lake gen v2 and attach these multiple files in an email. As a first step I have added http request and I am giving required information along with file path. It works fine for one file. but I am trying to input folder path and inside that folder, all the files I want to get and attach in email.

[Logic app Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRpCp.png)

Added sample screenshot for attachment

[tried to add attchment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO7ut.png)

In the above diagram, Get blob content step which works fine for one file but I am finding difficult to attach multiple files in email. Can some one help me to figure out the solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Logic app : How to Send an Email with one or more attachments after getting the content from Blob storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473878/azure-logic-app-how-to-send-an-email-with-one-or-more-attachments-after-gettin)

Comment: Hi John. No I already went through that question. That will send multiple emails but i want to add multiple files in same email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List blobs` action to list all blobs in the folder you want:

[image]

Then you can define a variable to append the attachments array.

[image]

Use `For Each` to loop the blobs from `List Blobs` action. Within `For Each` you can use `Get blob content` to get blob content, and then use `Append to array variable` to append attachments.

The expressions of `Path`, `DisplayName` and `File Content` are as follows:

```
Path : items('For_each')?['Path']

DisplayName : items('For_each')?['DisplayName']

File Content : body('Get_blob_content')
```

[image]

[image]

Finally, please fill in the attachment in the email:

[image]

==========================update===================

If you send an email with 400 response, please use expression in `Append to array variable` as below:

```
base64(body('Get_blob_content'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you Frank gong. When I add expression to path @items('For each')?['Path'] I am getting invalid expression. what would be the issue any thing I am missing?

Comment: Please try [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i94h1.png).

Comment: Thanks It worked but I was trying to give expression Path : items('For_each')?['Path']. So same thing for displayName and Contentbytes right?

Comment: Yes, `displayName` and `Contentbytes` also apply.

Comment: I came to last step of sending email. In attachments I do not see {x}attachments. I will upload sample screenshot here

Comment: Please click [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMx0P.png) to switch to input entire array.

Comment: I recieved multiple attachments email but I recieved email also twice because I had two attachments.

Comment: Please make sure that `send email` is outside `for each`

Comment: The workflow is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXXgx.png).