# Send Email with multiple attachment using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to send the blobs uploaded to my Azure storage container as an attachments. Number of files getting uploaded to container will change so I need to use dynamic method for attachment.
[I have verified this question related to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784466/how-to-get-multiple-files-using-getbobcontent-and-add-as-attachment-to-email-in)

I am using below logic:

[image]

**Append to variable values**

{

```
"Name": items('For_each')?['DisplayName']
"ContentBytes":body('Get_blob_content')
```

}
When I am trying to save the logic, getting below error:

```
Save logic app failed
Failed to save logic app testing. The template validation failed: 'The action(s) 'Get_blob_content' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Append_to_array_variable' are not defined in the template.'.
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: By following the above shared steps, we have created a workflow & tested in Our local environment which is working fine 
Here is the [screen shot](https://i.imgur.com/JzTnbV5.png) for your reference: 

We have used the same logic in the `appendtoarrayvariable` & able to save the logic app as shown in this [GIF](https://imgur.com/BJo8pJe) .

Comment: Instead, of saving the entire workflow at once would suggest you to save the logic app at each stage or before the `appendtoarray` variable stage & post then append the values to  attachment variable with previous stage outputs.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT: Thanks. It giving error https://imgur.com/a/lQ3SSd9  in for loop. In Get Blob content inside loop, how me mention the blob ? DO we need to take reference from List Blob or from the first trigger (When lob is uploaded). Sorry, I am new to this and getting confused with it

Comment: please refer the blob path , from the list blob operations only in  get blob content action 
as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/3SQiBPR.png)

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT: Thanks, made changes. I am getting error at send email action now. This is the error - https://imgur.com/a/lQ3SSd9

Comment: Please use the below expression for the content variable "Content": `base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))` in the Append to array variable block as shown in below image `https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI7kP.png

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT: Thanks, it worked now. But I am getting more than one email with multiple attachment. Send email action is out side for loop. Any suggestions - https://imgur.com/a/ubVjCEE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240224/discussion-between-venkateshdodda-mt-and-acr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message shared above, Instead of saving the entire workflow at once would suggest you to save the logic app at each stage or before the `appendtoarray` variable stage & post then append the values to attachment variable with previous stage outputs.

Based on the above requirement, we have created the below logic app in our local environment &tested it as well which is working fine.

In our workflow, We have Used `For Each` to loop the blobs from `List Blobs` action. Within For Each you can use `Get blob content` to get blob content, and then use Append to array variable to append attachments.

The expressions Name and ContentBytes are as follows:

```
 "ContentBytes": "@base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))",
 "Name": "@items('For_each')?['DisplayName']"
```

[image]

**Here is the code view of the Logic app that we have created :**

```html
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "attachments",
                            "value": {
                                "ContentBytes": "@base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))",
                                "Name": "@items('For_each')?['DisplayName']"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}/content",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "attachments",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmcmVwb3J0cw=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcmVwb3J0cw==": "/reports"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Attachments": "@variables('attachments')",
                        "Body": "<p>tested logic app flow successfully</p>",
                        "Subject": "blob test",
                        "To": "<username>@microsoft.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmcmVwb3J0cw==",
                        "maxFileCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcmVwb3J0cw==": "/reports"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<sub-ID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<resroucegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]