# azure logic app to grab email attachment slow to trigger

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a azure logic app that monitors my emails and when target is found, it drops the attachment into blob storage.  The plan is a consumption plan.

The issue is, sometimes it takes up to 50 minutes for the email to be grabbed and dropped.  I know there is a startup time when things go idle, but I was reading seconds/minutes.  Not close to an hour.  Does anyone know how I can trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes it takes up to 50 minutes to grab and drop the email

Based on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftpconnector/#trigger-limits) ,
The reason for delay is:

*When the triggers encounter a new file, it will try to ensure that the new file is completely written. For instance, it is possible that the file is being written or modified, and updates are being made at the time the trigger polled the file server. To avoid returning a file with partial content, the trigger will take note of the timestamp such files which are modified recently, but will not immediately return those files. Those files will be returned only when the trigger polls again. Sometimes, **this may lead a delay** up to twice the trigger polling interval. This also means that the trigger does not guarantee to return all files in a single run when "Split On" option is disabled.*

For more information you can refer this:

. [Automate tasks to process emails by using Azure Logic Apps | MS DOC,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) .

.[How to Send an Email with one or more attachments after getting the content from Blob storage? | SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473878/azure-logic-app-how-to-send-an-email-with-one-or-more-attachments-after-gettin) & [Logic app Created with add email attachments in Blob storage  .](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-logic-apps-with-step-by-step-demo-part-2/%20.)